# How to use customer token to access my account Query or Mutation in GraphQl

Tags: header, magento2.3, token, authorize, graphql

I am using magetno 2.3.x and I want to access my account queries provided by  Magento_CustomerGraphQl module.

I have installed ChromeiQl to execute GraphQl.
I set Site Endpoint as per syntax provided by magento [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/).

I have generated the customer token using provided type Mutation

```
type Mutation {
    generateCustomerToken(email: String!, password: String!)
    {
      token
    }
}
```

But I did not get any way to use this token in ChromiQL as authorization Header.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try this:

**Step 1:** Get a bearer token:
You can get a token by executing the signup mutation in the playground to create a new user. This is the signup mutation I ran:

```
Request:

mutation {
      generateCustomerToken(email: "customer@example.com", password: "password") {
      token
  }
}

Response:

 {
  "data": {
     "generateCustomerToken": {
     "token": "hoyz7k697ubsdsdfsdfsdfsdfv5hcpq92yrtx39i7x"
     }
   }
 }
```

**Step 2:** Include the bearer token in your request

Notice there is a text area called HTTP HEADERS at the bottom of the playground. Paste the following code into HTTP HEADERS, replacing your-token-goes-here with the bearer token returned by the server in step 1:

```
{
   "Authorization": "Bearer zcnj8wd03u19s5fw1yvkprs23du7tfkh"
}
```

**Step 3:** Run the post mutation
Now that you are including a bearer token in your request you can run the post mutation.

Please check and let me know if you are able to get the response.

Comment: Is it required to add a Bearer token for returning the response?

Comment: Does this still works? it used to work for me but after the latest updates, not working for me

Answer (score 3):

The resulting token should be used in subsequent requests in the `Authorization` header as a `Bearer` token ex:
`Authorization: Bearer {{resultFromGenerateCustomerToken}}`

I don't think ChromeQL allows the setting request Headers. If you are on OSX you can use this electron app which give you access to set the headers. https://github.com/skevy/graphiql-app

Additionally, the graphiql included in the PWA Studio includes the same functionality https://github.com/magento-research/pwa-studio

Comment: Thankyou for your response, you are right ChrmeQL does no provide setting for request header so I ended up with GraphiQLFeen.

Comment: @KapilDevSingh, If you use Altair (chrome extension) then it provides the feature to set request headers in it. I have used it already.